# what are the new swing components which are not there in netbeans?

Tags: java, swing

I searched and found JCalendar only  ... We need to simply download the .jar file of JCalendar from google and add it netbeans

For adding go to

tools,
palette,
Swing / Awt Components,
Add jar file,
locate your downloaded file,
Right on palette window on left side and refresh..

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: there are multiple 'open source' libraries-jar files that are available and this is one of them .

Comment: @AHungerArtist  It seems to be the title.  The rest could be interpreted as proof of effort.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third-party additions to swing

Answer (score 3):

[JCalendar](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/) is not a Swing component, since it is not part of the official Swing distribution.

It is an excellent third party component, kindly made available to the community by Kai Toedter, the programmer who wrote it and is a Java date chooser bean for graphically picking a date, composed of several other Java beans like a JDayChooser, a JMonthChooser and a JYearChooser.

[Beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/quick/addbean.html) can easily extend the toolbox of any GUI builder. You can design your own beans at any time and add them to your toolbox.

There was a site called nbextras.org with NetBeans plug-ins. The idea was to be able to get and update the beans. Now nbextras is down and has been replaced by the official [NetBeans Plugin Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/).

You should feel safe however, that whenever new things appear in Swing, they will become available in the next version on Netbeans.